# Regex pattern matching in old versions of bash

Tags: bash, git-bash

Aim: write client side git hook to check commit-msg complying to the policy.

For this I have written a bash script that matches the pattern of the commit message with the regex.
It seems to work with newer version of bash

```
if [[ ! "$START_LINE" =~ $PATTERN ]]; then
```

but `=~` does not seem to work with old versions of bash.

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.1.20(4)-release (i686-pc-msys
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

```
PATTERN="^[[:alpha:]]{2,6}[-][[:digit:]]{0,9}[-](AISP|PISP)[-][v][[:digit:]][.][[:digit:]]"
```

My teammates are using old version of bash and I cannot force them to shift to new one. Is there a way to work through pattern matching without using `=~` operator?
Exact error :

```
$ git commit -m "dsdsd" .git/hooks/commit-msg: line 5: conditional
binary operator expected .git/hooks/commit-msg: line 5: syntax error
near =~' .git/hooks/commit-msg: line 5: if [[ ! "$START_LINE" =~
$PATTERN ]]; then'
```

I have gone through all posts on internet including SO but they all are suggesting use of `=~` or moving on to new version of bash.

Comment: (Won't solve @ankita-m 's use case, but) **IF** your regex needs are **simple** you might be able to get away with the string manipulations that are part of bash variable substitution:  F/ex: Does it start with "Hello"?  `if [ "${LINE:0:5}" == 'Hello' ] ;`  F/ex Does it end with "last"?  `if [ "${LINE:(-4)}" == 'last' ] ;`  F/ex: is it all lower case?  `if [ -z "${LINE//[a-z]/}" ] ;` etc.   NOTE: when the bash manual talks about "patterns" for these it mean glob-like patterns (not regex patterns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if ! echo "$FIRST_LINE" | grep -Eqe "$PATTERN"; then
```

or (if your shell supports here-strings `<<<`)

```
if ! grep -Eqe "$PATTERN" <<< "$FIRST_LINE"; then
```

**PS:** By convention all-capital variable names are reserved for environment and shell variables. Use lowercase variables like `$pattern` and `$firstLine` to avoid accidental name collisions.

**PPS:** Your regex could be slightly simplified. `[v]` is the same as `v` and so on.

```
^[[:alpha:]]{2,6}[-][[:digit:]]{0,9}-[-][v][[:digit:]][.][[:digit:]]
^[[:alpha:]]{2,6}-[[:digit:]]{0,9}--v[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) it works I was literally stuck on this. Can you explain how I should be calling sed or perl? Also thanks for editing my question I will keep in mind next time while posting a question

Comment: @ankitam `grep` is the best way to do it. With `if sed -En "/$pattern/q1" <<< "$firstLine"` you have to make sure, that `$pattern` does not contain `/` and the command is more complicated than the `grep` command. Same goes for `perl`.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for suggesting. I changed the regex too and changed variable names to be in lower case but if ! grep -Eq "$PATTERN" <<< "$FIRST_LINE"; then doesnot seem to work even when the regex matches.

Comment: When you change the variable names, you have to change them everywhere.

Comment: hey! yes thanks I made the change everywhere. Apologies, I double checked my script the error is with getting the git commit msg. still trying to figure it out... input=$1 is returning .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG instead of actual commit message

Comment: @ankitam Documentation commit-msg hooks: *»It takes a single parameter,
the name of the file that holds the proposed commit log message.«* To read the first line from that file, use `firstLine="$(head -n1 "$1")"`.

Comment: PPPS - `grep`'s  `-q` option to be quiet (not print matching lines) isn't available everywhere.  So if you want more portability you can omit `-q` and add `>/dev/null` onto the end of the if command (before `; then`)

Comment: @DouglasDD Thank you for your input. The unsupported `-q` is quite interesting as [`-q` is specified in posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html). Can you link/name an implementation that does not support `-q`? I'd really love to investigate this.

Comment: @Socowi older versions of Mac OS X.   Current Mac versions (10.14, 10.15) `/usr/bin/grep` does support `-q`.  
But this was definitely an issue back in 10.5, 10.6 era (where PPC & x86-32 machines are stuck).
Unfortunately my older machines are unavailable to test right now.

Answer (score 0):

@Socowi's answer I think is the right one.

You can write in in an alternative way that if you are used to use grep with files might be more intuitive (I typically mess is up with the order of pattern and string to compare), or at least is the one I use for default just because of that,

```
if ! grep -Eq "$PATTERN" <(echo "$FIRST_LINE"); then
```